# How to convert byte[] to GameObject? (unity android)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I download a `GameObject(FBX format)` from the Url and save as a `byte[]`. After saving, I can not access the file on Android and I want to convert it to `GameObject` after downloading from the byte.

Also `Resources.Load` not working!
This is my code snippet:

```
IEnumerator DownloadFBX()
{
    using (var webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(Url))
    {
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
        if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.LogError(webRequest.error);
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Resources/", "Handgun.fbx"), webRequest.downloadHandler.data);
            // Now I want create GameObject from byte[]. Resources.Load not working !
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to do what you are trying to do. Unity can't directly load an FBX into a GameObject. Check out [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/903028/how-to-convert-byte-to-gameobject.html) link to the Unity forums where someone asked a similar question.

The best method would be to create a GameObject with your FBX in the Unity editor and then create an AssetBundle with it. Then you can load that AssetBundle at runtime.